# (When list mix with text & numbers) How to convert numbers in each small list into numeric instead of string within that big list in python?

Tags: python

The list is mixed with both text and numbers. And so far they all have ' ' symbol, means they are all string? So how to convert numbers in each small list into numeric instead of string within that big list in python?

**This is what I have:**

wholeList = [ ['apple','1','2'],['banana','2','3'],['cherry', '3','4'],['downypitch', '4','5'] ]

**This is what I want:**
text such as apple have type string, while the numbers such as 2 have type numeric

newList = [ [apple,1,2],[banana,2,3],[cherry, 3,4],[downypitch, 4,5]]

**This is what I tried:**

```
newList = []

for t in wholeList:
    for j in num_part:
        new_part = int(j)
        newList.append(new_part)

print(newList)
```

However, this gives me something like this:

[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I am assuming that 0-th entry remains to be string, while 1st, 2nd, ... are to be converted into integers.

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```py
whole_list = [ ['apple','1','2'],['banana','2','3'],['cherry', '3','4'],['downypitch', '4','5'] ]

new_list = [[sublst[0], *map(int, sublst[1:])] for sublst in whole_list]
print(new_list) # [['apple', 1, 2], ['banana', 2, 3], ['cherry', 3, 4], ['downypitch', 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that allows for the number strings being anywhere in the sublists and for the sublists to be of any length:

```
wholeList = [ ['apple','1','2'],['banana','2','3'],['cherry', '3','4'],['downypitch', '4','5'] ]
newList = wholeList[:]
for e in newList:
    for i, x in enumerate(e):
        try:
            e[i] = int(e[i])
        except ValueError:
            pass
print(newList)
```

**Output:**

```
[['apple', 1, 2], ['banana', 2, 3], ['cherry', 3, 4], ['downypitch', 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Would you mind explain a bit more about ```for i, x in enumerate(e):``` ? What this for loop is doing? What is ```x``` stands for? And why we use 2 indicator ```i``` and ```x``` here?  As this is the 1st time I saw two parameters in one for loop. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

**If you have mixture of text and number, this would be the best solution**

***Because string can appear at any location***

```
wholeList = [ ['apple','1','2'],['2','banana', '3'],['3','4', 'cherry'],['downypitch', '4','5'] ]
newlist = []
for sublist in wholeList:
   temp = []
   for string in sublist:
       try:
           temp.append(int(string))
       except:
            temp.append(string)
   newlist.append(temp)
print(newlist)
# op: wholeList = [ ['apple','1','2'],['2','banana', '3'],['3','4', 'cherry'],['downypitch', '4','5'] ]
```